Conexion con google provider sin token error?
Hola buenas a todos necesito que me ayuden con lo siguiente estoy intentando conectar mi app en next.js con NextAuth.js con un provider de google he logrado iniciar sesion con google pero dentro de la app se debe enviar un formulario con ciertos datos para que se escriban en una hoja de calculo de google sheet pero ahi es donde falla ya que no puedo obtener un token para que logre eso o por lo menos es lo que yo creo me ayudan gracias.


import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { updateGoogleSheet } from "../../app/services/updateSheet";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === "GET") {
        const { code } = req.body;

        try {
            const response = await fetch("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
                body: new URLSearchParams({
                    client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                    client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    redirect_uri: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/callback/google`,
                    grant_type: "authorization_code",
                    code,
                }),
            });

            const { access_token } = await response.json();

            const session = await getSession({ req });
            session.accessToken = access_token;

            const spreadsheetId = "1EwHv2SdCnNVd3IsCTmYBxyoBme4mm0rtxqe0Jbs7wXU";
            const range = "A1:B1";
            const value = "";

            await updateGoogleSheet(spreadsheetId, range, value, session.accessToken);

            res
                .status(200)
                .json({ message: "Token de acceso guardado y lista para usar." });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(
                "Error exchanging authorization code for access token:",
                error
            );
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error");
        }
    } else {
        res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET"]);
        res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
    }
}



este archivo deberia obtener el token y pasarlo
configuracion del provider


import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL =
    `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/callback/google` +
    "?prompt=select_account&access_type=offline&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/signin",
        signOut: "/auth/signout",
        error: "/auth/error",
        newUser: null,
    },
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token }) {
            console.log(token);
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            session.user.id = token;

            return session;
        },
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});



aqui la funcion


export async function updateGoogleSheet(
    spreadsheetId,
    range,
    value,
    accessToken
) {
    const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${range}:append`;
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            values: [[value]],
        }),
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            "Error al actualizar el estado y la fila en Google Sheets:",
            error.message
        );
        if (error.response) {
            console.error("Datos:", error.response.data);
            console.error("Estado:", error.response.status);
            console.error("Headers:", error.response.headers);
        }
        throw error;
    }
}





const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!newStates.length || !row.trim() || !column.trim()) {
            return alert(
                "Por favor, selecciona un estado y especifica una fila y columna."
            );
        }

        const range = `${String.fromCharCode(65 + parseInt(column))}${
            parseInt(row) + 1
        }`;
        const spreadsheetId = "1EwHv2SdCnNVd3IsCTmYBxyoBme4mm0rtxqe0Jbs7wXU";

        try {
            const tokenResponse = await fetch("/api/token");
            if (!tokenResponse.ok) {
                throw new Error("Error al obtener el accessToken");
            }
            const { accessToken } = await tokenResponse.json();

            await updateGoogleSheet(spreadsheetId, range, "Nuevo Valor", accessToken);
            alert("Datos guardados exitosamente!");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(
                "Error al actualizar el estado y la fila en Google Sheets:",
                error
            );
            alert("Hubo un error al intentar guardar los datos.");
        }
    };



el submit del form
y esto devulve en consola

necesito poder obtener el token para poder escribir en google sheet
